# Ng for with call functions

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, ngfor

I develop chat app using ionic 2. Here is my html code

```html
<ion-content padding>

  <div *ngIf="online === true">
      <ion-refresher (ionRefresh)="onPullOldMessages($event)">
          <ion-refresher-content></ion-refresher-content>
      </ion-refresher>
    <div class="chat" *ngIf="chatval">
      <div class="messagesholder" 
      *ngFor="let chat of chatval | orderby:'[date]';  let i = index;let first=first;let last = last;">

             <div *ngIf="chat.sender == currentuser || chat.receiver == currentuser" >
                   <p class="chat-date"   id="abc" #abc>{{chat.date | amDateFormat:'LL'}}</p>
                   {{checkdate(chat.date)}} 
              </div> 

         <div class="message" *ngIf="chat.sender == currentuser || chat.receiver == currentuser" [ngClass]="{'me': currentuser == chat.sender}">
                <div class='image' *ngIf="chat.path" >
                  <img *ngIf="chat.path" [src]="chat.path" imageViewer/><br>
                  <span *ngIf="chat.path_text">{{chat.path_text}}</span>
                  <span style="font-size:9px;">{{chat.date | amDateFormat:'hh:mmA'}}</span>
                </div> 
                 <div *ngIf="chat.message_text">
                 <span>{{chat.message_text}}</span>
                 <span style="font-size:9px;">{{chat.date | amDateFormat:'hh:mmA'}}</span>
                 </div>
          </div>
     </div>
   </div>  
 </div>
</ion-content>
```

It works fine. Display chat msg. But I need does not display same date value because I called `checkdate(chat.date)`.

Here is my function

```ts
checkdate(date)
  {
    var res = date.split(" ");
    var A=res[0];
    var local=localStorage.getItem('chatdate');
    this.msgdate="";
    if(local === undefined || local === null)
    {
      this.msgdate=A;
      localStorage.setItem('chatdate',this.msgdate);

    }
    else if(local !== undefined)
    {
      console.log(local != A);
      if(local != A)
      {

        this.msgdate = A;
         localStorage.setItem('chatdate',this.msgdate);
      }
    }
   console.log("date value");
   }
```

Actually array length is 3. But this function called many time. I was checked how many times this function called. Because I just consoled the string value. It consoled many times, like 100 times.

How can I stop repeatedly called function?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this, is that you are calling the function from the template:

```
{{checkdate(chat.date)}}
```

This is something you would really want to avoid, since having functions in the template, means that they are executed each time change detection is run. In worst case, this causes an infinite loop.

So the suggestion is to refactor your code as such, that you handle the logic in your component, assign it to variable(s), and use variables in the template.

Comment: Thanks.I assigned variable update only array of last item value.

Comment: Sorry, I'm having trouble understanding what you mean :) Could you show the code instead of what you have tried?

Comment: I have array with 3 values.The array value contains msg and date.date values are same.Acutally My app is displayed same date values.i need does not display same date values How can i check...

Comment: Still not really understandinfg, could you please create a plunker that showcases this issue and I'd be happy to take a look :)